# Avoiding exponential values in CSV on loading to Database

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, azure-data-factory

I am using a python script in order to structure a CSV file fetched from a website and store it as CSV in Azure container. The CSV File is loaded into Azure database using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity.

The datatype one of the amount column in CSV is having Exponential value inside it.For example it has value **3.7E+08** (the actual value is **369719968** ). But when the data is loaded into the database the values are stored as 3.7E+08 in the staging table for which the column data type is `varchar(30)`. I am converting it to float and then to decimal in order to store it in the target table. On converting to `float` the value is coming as **370000000** inside database and hence it causing a big mismatch in the amount.

Kindly suggest how we can resolve this issue. We tried to convert the amount column to string in the CSV using Python. But still the value is coming as exponential.

Comment: It sounds like the Python script generating your CSV output is using `%g` format specifiers for numbers instead of `%d`. Compare the output of `print '{:g}'.format(369719968)` against `print '{:d}'.format(369719968)`.

Comment: ok let me check it

Comment: We are not using any format specifiers.We are just renaming the columns and  data resides in one column,so  we add  delimiter to the columns.This issue occurs very rarely.Sometimes this issue is not found